# Android - Determine if the app is started or brought to the front from notification click

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

My app issues notifications. By clicking the notification, the app needs to be launched or brought to the front. Here is the intent for the notification:

```
    Intent launch_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    launch_intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.helloworld","com.example.helloworld.MainActivity"));
    launch_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    launch_intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    launch_intent.putExtra("some_data", "value");
```

And in my app I want to determine if it's launched or brought to the front by the notification click, so I use putExtra there. Then in MainActivity's onResume I check the intent data. This works fine is the app is launched by the notification click.

However, if the app is brought to the front by the notification click, in MainActivity's onResume there is no intent data.

I think the reason is: MainActivity is the root activity, and it's the splash screen. There could be any number of activities on top of it when the app is brought to the front. And when it's brought to the front, I want to keep its state.

What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: Check in `onNewIntent()` method.

Comment: But I'm not using flag_activity_single_top. When the app is brought to the front, I want to keep its state.

Answer (score 0):

Override [`onNewIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) in your activity and check the value there. If you want future calls to `getIntent()` to return this new intent, you can call [`setIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setIntent(android.content.Intent)) and pass the new intent.

Comment: But I'm not using flag_activity_single_top. When the app is brought to the front, I want to keep its state.

Answer (score 0):

Try in `onNewIntent()` method

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    String value = intent.getStringExtra("some_data");
}
```

Comment: But I'm not using flag_activity_single_top. When the app is brought to the front, I want to keep its state.

Comment: It wont force activity to reset.